# Access to first json element

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have to following (to me "mysterious") behavior:

The following used to work (XAMPP, PHP 5.5.15):

```
$data['item_domain'] = json_decode($this->input->post('item_info'))[0];
```

But since I moved to a (LAMP, PHP 5.3.3) it does not work more, error is:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' ...
```

As a workaround I am using this (... I know... don't hit me :-) )

```
$json_decoded = json_decode($this->input->post('item_info'));    
$data['item_domain'] ="";    
foreach($json_decoded as $items) { $data['item_domain'] = $items;  break;}
```

Someone any clue?

Comment: well if it is an simple json array, why dont use of indexes like `$data['item_domain'] = $json_decoded[0]` ?

Comment: the answer bellow is excactly what i said, just 1 sek faster and with the first line without [0] at its end

Comment: Yes, you were right, sorry for that. I made a typo in my code. Thanks lad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json_decoded = json_decode($this->input->post('item_info'));
$data['item_domain'] = $json_decoded[0];
```

You have downgraded your PHP version.  That syntax is only available from 5.4

Comment: Please don't upvote me for this...